# How to avoid allocation when accessing struct? Julia

Tags: memory-management, julia

I'm trying my function call to have as little memory allocation as possible to make it run faster. The problem is that it seems when I access a struct that is given as argument there are many allocations.

```
function mCondition(y,t,integrator)
    xp, yp, zp, vx, vy, vz = y
    mu = integrator.p[1]
    cond = (xp - 1.0 + mu)*vx +  yp*vy + zp*vz
    return cond
end
struct myStr
    p
    u
end

y = rand(6)
t = 0.0
A = myStr([0.01215],rand(6))

#test call
mCondition(y,t,A)

using BenchmarkTools
@btime mCondition(y,t,A)
```

The output is:

```
julia> @btime mCondition(y,t,A)
  102.757 ns (9 allocations: 144 bytes)
-0.07935578340713843
```

I think that the problem is with the struct because when I delete that part of the code,

```
function mCondition(y,t,integrator)
    xp, yp, zp, vx, vy, vz = y
    cond = (xp - 1.0)*vx +  yp*vy + zp*vz
    return cond
end
```

this is the result of the benchmark:

```
julia> @btime mCondition(y,t,A)
  18.294 ns (1 allocation: 16 bytes)
-0.08427348469961408
```

which is closer to what I would expect of whats going on inside the function (but I still wonder if that allocation is even necessary). If you could help me understand whats going on or even fix it that would be nice.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to type annotate field definitions in your `struct` to enable the compiler to generate high-performance code. Without type annotations in your `struct` fields, the compiler cannot infer the types of the fields at compile-time which would leave the decisions to run-time and hence this would hurt performance and cause otherwise unnecessary allocations.

The solution is then,

```
struct myStr
    p::Vector{Float64}
    u::Vector{Float64}
end
```

You can also make your `struct` parametric, for example, if you want it to work with `Vector`s of other types. See the [Types](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/) section of documentation for more information.

I would also suggest that you read the [Performance Tips](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#Avoid-fields-with-abstract-type-1) section of documentation to learn more about how to write high-performance code in Julia.

Comment: Thanks that was really helpful. I really have to learn a lot more, I'll keep reading the documentation.